# How To Make Code inline in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email, post, inline, execute

I have the following code which I would like to place in my website:

```
<%
    Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
    myMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
    myMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"
    myMail.TextBody="This is a message."
    myMail.Send
    set myMail=nothing
%>
```

The condition is that This whole code should be placed in one line, For example:

`<% Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message") myMail.Subject="Sending email...`

But the above code doesn't work, can someone tell me how do it make the code properly execute when placed in one line as I have to send this code via a POST to a page.(don't ask me why)

Comment: looks like classic asp, not asp.net

Comment: @MichaelB. Between Each line? I want it on only one line.

Comment: sorry, put all in one line but use : as separator between each statement